# javascript add text to multiple elements

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add text to multiple elements using javascript?

This is the original content.

```
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
```

This is what happens when you add text using javascript.

```
<div class="container">Hello, I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">Hello, I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">Hello, I am Arun</div>
```

I tried searching for answers online and many people mentioned the following methods.

```
.createTextNode()
.insertAdjacentText()
.insertAdjacentHTML()
Node.textContent
```

But they cannot be applied to multiple elements, i.e. `document.getElementsByClassName('container')`.

May I ask if my understanding is correct? Any help is appreciated in advance!

Comment: You can use @AbsoluteBeginner's answer and still use `var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('container')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **document.querySelectorAll**.

My suggestion:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].innerHTML = "Hello, " + divs[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
```

About **document.querySelectorAll**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS Pseudo-element [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

```css
.container::before {
  content: 'Hello, '
}
```

```html
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
<div class="container">I am Arun</div>
```